# Unresolved constraint issue while starting the httpclient-osgi bundle on apache felix

Tags: osgi, constraints, httpclient

I am running into issue while starting up httpclient-osgi-4.3.2 on apache felix.

The error is:

**Unresolved constraint in bundle org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient [126]: Unable to resolve 126.0: missing requirement [126.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.http.concurrent)(version>=4.3.0)(!(version>=4.4.0)))**

Wondering if anyone has run into a similar issue and been able to resolve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't have this issue, but it seems you are missing the Apache HttpCore bundle (version between 4.3 and 4.4). Can be found [here](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi).